# Having multiple reducers create multiple output files in HDFS

Tags: hadoop

If I have multiple reducers will the output be saved as multiple files?

If I have `job.setNumReduceTasks(4)`, will the output write to 4 different files?

Comment: Yes, one output per reducer. Try it once, you will understand

Answer (score 1):

In map-reduce job, if you set 4 reducers to implement the reducer jobs. By doing this, the final output will generate 4 part-files. like **part-r-00001**, **part-r-00002**, **part-r-00003**, **part-r-00004**. hope this clarify your doubts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, so if we have multiple reducers, Say If i have to calculate a single consolidated value, say a max number, how will i do that? Say if i have 4 reducers, then the output will be 4 max numbers from different reducers based on partition??

Comment: in this case why do you need to use reducer? Mapper can server your request.

Comment: How can Mapper server the consolidated request? We will have multiple mappers serving a Job, which generates key value pairs, where will the aggregation happens? Even if we use combiner it will be specific to the mappers output. It is bit confusing,  could you please elaborate your answer? Thank you!